# Conditional Formatting in Excel: Max value that is not zero

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have columns with zero or positive float values. My current format condition is:

<kbd>Cell value is</kbd> <kbd>equal to</kbd> `=AND(MAX($A$1:$A$50),A1<>0)`

The idea of this conditional format is to format only cells that are not

The `A1` (not `$A$1`) part is the current cell. It can be from `A1` to `A50`. They are currently no format when all of them are zeroes. But when I modified one of the cell to any positive value, let say `0.01`, the formatting does not take effect.

What is the correct condition for this case?

Comment: if any number entered will always be positive, the 2nd condition is unnecessary. Just use `Max`... or am I missing something? ... the reason this does not work is because as of now `A1` effectively equals 0, since there is nothing in it.

Comment: I was going to say that conditional formatting is based on a logical comparison of some sort.  You make one comparison, and one get me a value operation which returns a number.  In the eyes of excel, 0 is false, and any other number is true.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:  `=AND(MAX($A$1:$A$50)=A1,A1<>0)`  The range was `A1:A50`.  It highlighted the maximum value only.

Comment: when applying the conditional formula with the above formula make sure that cell A1 is the active cell in your selection.  IF it is not the A1 address will get updated incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks @Forward Ed, i forgot to mention that.

Comment: NP, just trying to round out the answer.  It was an aspect of conditional formatting that took me a long time to realize.